Severely burned man has plastic surgery to get his revenge
This movie is about two doctors searching for a way to change the human face quickly and easily with a new type of plastic surgery. However, near the end of their research they are attacked by criminals and severely injured. One of the doctors dies and the another survives - but with almost no face as he is seriously burned.
The surviving doctor then tries to find the survived parts from their lab and complete the research, so he can repair his face and take his revenge.

It's probably not "Face/Off", but it's got a similar concept.  Do you recall the country of origin?  Any specific actors?  Approximate year of release?

No, its not "Face/off". Dont have such information, ive been watching it long time age. As I remember language was English. Another I remember is that the criminals used "duck drinking water" toy for timer to detonate the bombs. Nothing else for now comes in my head.

Possibly Darkman from 1990.
imdb
wikipedia
theatrical trailer

A brilliant scientist left for dead returns to exact revenge on the
  people who burned him alive.


Lol. Thank you very much, you fast. :)

@Alexander - You're in for a treat. Great little cult movie starring a then unknown Liam Neeson.
